# find all links with regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, hyperlink, html-content-extraction

I have a text full of link address with style

```
href=\'http://address.com\'
```

I use `re.findall('"((http)s?://.*?)"', srcCode)` in Python 3.4 to extract all links, but doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

swap the quotes

```
re.findall("'((http)s?://.*?)'", srcCode)
```

Comment: Should be `(?:http)` if the OP doesn't want to capture that separately

Comment: i tested this, but doesn't work :(. this re when works that my test has `href='http://address.com'` but my text has link with style `href=\'http://address.com\'`.

Comment: when i run, return epmty list [].

Comment: re should be `re.findall("'((http)s?://.*?).\'", srcCode)`

Comment: there is not any difference between `"'((http)s?://.*?).\'"` and `"'((http)s?://.*?).'"`
the both have same result in console